# Oracle change column type from DATE to VARCHCAR2

Tags: oracle

I have column with name `DATA_STR` and type `DATE`. I need change column type to `VARCHAR2(50)`. How can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to store your dates as text?  This usually isn't a good idea.

Comment: Why on earth would you want to do that? You should never store DATE values as VARCHAR.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen I store date in 2 columns. In first as date, in second as string. In short, it is connected with a digital signature, which breaks down when I convert the date I received as a string to a Java date, then save it in the database, and turn it back into a string

Comment: Certainly you do not **need** to do that.

Comment: You should listen to everyone here who's repeatedly warning you against using strings for dates. I hope you realise the fact that you are going  in a wrong direction by doing so.

Comment: those who advise not to store dates as strings do not understand why I am doing this. And if they understand and still instruct, let them tell me how to store the date `2018-08-02` and `2018-08-02+6:00` and `2018-08-02Z`  in one column? https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_dtypes_date.asp

Comment: You are referring to a link that's not even related to SQL,forget Oracle.Did you try to understand how date datatype works in Oracle and how it's different from XSD or whatever you are  linking to? Have you explored other datatypes that are available in Oracle ( like TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE , INTERVAL etc) which may help you to store other time parameters? By the way did you know `DATE`  type in Oracle  itself can also store time component ? If the experts are saying it that's because you have not clearly explained the the problem,you just concluded from somewhere that you need char

Comment: Adding to that there are  wide varieties of Oracle  functions to transform your source string into the above said datatypes.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not recommended, you can follow the steps

1. Add new (temp) column `DATA_STR_VAR`
2. Update it using old column with [to_char](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions180.htm) e.g.:

   ```
   update tableName set DATA_STR_VAR=to_char(DATA_STR, 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI')
   ```
3. Drop column `DATA_STR`
4. Rename `DATA_STR_VAR` to `DATA_STR`

Comment: I need create script and execute it before update my server. How can I add all this steps to script?

Comment: @ip696 you can see all operations in https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/tables/alter_table.php

Comment: This will not work. `DATE` data type does not support neither time zone `TZH:TZM` nor fractional seconds.

Answer (score 1):

It was written already, however I repeat it: Do not do this!

But may you consider to use VIRTUAL COLUMN like this:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD DATE_CHAR GENERATED ALWAYS AS (TO_CHAR(DATA_STR, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') VIRTUAL);
```